# My setInterval doesn't work anymore for some reason

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

So i have this Button that adds swords which i need for my Incremental game, the swords should be adding one Soul (that's the "money" in the game) per second, it worked yesterday, and i just changed some of the CSS today, so i dunno why it doesn't work anymore.

```html
<button class="muchFancy" onclick="buySword()"> Buy a Sword </button>
```

```js
var Swords = 0;

function autoSoul(number) {
    souls = souls + number;
    document.getElementById('souls').innerHTML = souls;
}

function buySword() {
   var swordCost = Math.floor(30 * Math.pow(1.25, Swords));
   if (souls >= swordCost) {
       Swords = Swords + 1;
       souls = souls - swordCost;
       document.getElementById("Swords").innerHTML = Swords;
       document.getElementById("souls").innerHTML  = souls;
   };
   var nextSword  = Math.floor(30 * Math.pow(1.25, Swords));
   document.getElementById('swordCost').innerHTML = nextSword;
};

window.setInterval(function(){
    autoSoul(Swords);
}, 1000);
```

So, when i buy a sword it doesn't add one Soul per Second, it simply does nothing ... it worked yesterday so i don't have any idea why it doesn't work.

(Actually I'm not the only one thats working on the code, but he promised me he didn't change anything on the javascript ...)

Comment: Post the `Swords` and `souls` HTML elements

Comment: If the JavaScript didn't change, the he probably changed the id on the souls element

Comment: Add `var souls = 1;` directly below `var Swords = 0;` [Soul/Sword Fix Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPMPL/)

Comment: What happens if you put an `alert` into `autoSoul`, does it show up?

Comment: I made a JSFiddle for this, including a default value for souls: http://jsfiddle.net/gA7eF/

Comment: FYI, you should not be adding a `;` after a `function( ) { }` or an `if () { }` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  I think your `souls` variable is getting hoisted or something.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPMPL/1/)

**HTML**

```
<button class="muchFancy" id="muchFancy">Buy a Sword</button><br>
Swords: <div id="Swords">1</div>
souls: <div id="souls">150</div>
Cost: <div id="swordCost">5</div>
```

**JS**

```
var Swords = 1;
var souls = 150;

function autoSoul(number) {
    souls = souls + number;
    document.getElementById('souls').innerHTML = souls;
}

function buySword() {
    var swordCost = Math.floor(30 * Math.pow(1.25, Swords));
    if (souls >= swordCost) {
        Swords = Swords + 1;
        souls = souls - swordCost;
        document.getElementById("Swords").innerHTML = Swords;
        document.getElementById("souls").innerHTML = souls;
    }
    var nextSword = Math.floor(30 * Math.pow(1.25, Swords));
    document.getElementById('swordCost').innerHTML = nextSword;
}

window.setInterval(function () {
    autoSoul(Swords);
}, 1000);

document.getElementById("muchFancy").addEventListener("click", function(){
    buySword();
});
```

Comment: I deleted one other var i just created a day before ... and it works now for no goddamn reason I... uh thanks anyway, I tried what you gave me but it didn't work either.